# Visual Merchandiser Issue

Tags: magento-1.14

This is not something that happens instantaneously that I would be able to record and send in a video. What happens is that one day I will have a section organized and a few days later I’ll notice that a random product items has floated to the top of the category and mess up the organization that I set up for it.

Im using Magento 1 Enterprice Edition . Im not using third party extensions.

Does anybody knows for this issue ? If it`s related to any cache or configuration ?